# Where does the process reside in memory?

Tags: data-structures, operating-systems, memory-management

When a program runs in CPU, it turns into a process. In what kind of data structure is the **process** stored in a system memory?

In *Heap* or *Tree* or some other data structures?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 3):

A process is not a single data structure. In the Windows operating system, for example, a running process has a number of different structures in its memory including a copy of its PE header and its environment variables. Here is a table from a debugger showing the layout of one process after it has been loaded into memory:

[image: memory map]

The various pieces of data have different structures. For example, the PE header is a record, but the heap is usually some kind of tree or list.